# Combine 5 tables in Laravel and sort by created_at

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I'm making website for advertisements and people can publish things they are selling. So I have tables: `cars`, `technology`, `real_estate`, `pets` etc. All these tables have different columns except "created_at" column which is common for all tables.

Example:

> CARS: [Model, Type, fuel type..., created_at]
>
> PETS: [Name, Description..., created_at]

So if `cars` has 5 rows and `pets` has 7 and `real_estate` has 3 I need in return 15 rows sorted by `created_at`. I need to merge all 5 (or more) tables and sort them by created_at (without losing any of rows).
Do you have some tips or idea how to do that in laravel (Eloquent)?

Comment: I think this is more db schema problem.. `Advertisement` -- polymorph relation -- `models`

Comment: Can you help me somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there would be any useful things you can do to the query.  Unions require all queries to return the same amount of columns, you probably don't want to join these tables because that would just be a confused mess.  I believe the best solution would be to use `Collection`s.

```
$collection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection();
$sortedCollection = $collection->merge($pets)->merge($cars)->merge($realEsate)->sortBy('created_at');
```

Comment: variables in merge method stands for ex: $pets = Pet::all() ... Or it stands for table name "pets" ?

Comment: I did it with Pet::all() and it works.. Thank you very much!