# Laravel - getting data from a few tables ordered by created_at (not related)

Tags: laravel

I want to get data from a few tables (not related) and order it by created_at column.

For example I have tables:

**posts:**
id
title
text
created_at

**products:**
id
name
description
created_at

**users:**
id
name
email
created_at

As you see, on every table we have **created_at**, I want to get data from these tables sorted by created_at in one query. It will be similar to wall on Facebook.

Comment: you have not created any relationship between 3 tables so its not possible in 1 query

Comment: You need simple relation if u want to make it in one query

Comment: Also, usually order by `id` would give the same result.

Comment: I will do that with collection: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858480/5-tables-join-in-laravel-and-sort-by-created-at?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

As commented by some, you can't do this in a single query.

Use `Collection`s instead.

```
$posts = App\Post::all();
$products = App\Product::all();
$users = App\User::all();

$collection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection();
$collection = $collection->merge($posts)
                         ->merge($products)
                         ->merge($users)
                         ->sortBy('created_at');
```

Then use the `$collection` object to display the data.